# Is Single-member relation an equivalence

Tags: equivalence-relations

Single-member relation is an equivalence.

For example the relation R={(1,1)}.  Is R equivalence relation on a set?

Thanks.

Comment: $R$ is, but $(1,2)$ not.

Comment: "Is R equivalence relation on a set?" If the set is {1}, yes. Otherwise, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Not every single-member relation is an equivalence.

Counter-example: $R_2 = ${$(1, 2)$}

Comment: So $R_1 = ${$(1, 1)$} is  an equivalence?

Comment: Yes. But not any single-member relation

Comment: Actually $\{(1,1)\}$ is **not** an equivalence relation, except on the set $\{1\}$.

Comment: You mean the relation $R_1 = ${$(1,1)$} on set   $S = ${$1, 2, 3, 4$} , is not an equivalence?

Comment: @wokwok: no it isn't since it doesn't contain $(2,2)$, $(3,3)$, or $(4,4)$.